# Service Endpoint not working for Azure Functions Proxies, behind an Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-gateway, azure-function-app-proxy

I'm using an Application Gateway (WAF) to route all traffic to a Proxy Function App (Premium EP1). The function app in turn takes URLs like the following and directs them to their correct Web API. (I realise this is a feature of the Path Based Routing in App Gateway, but we also do header injection to provide the correct Tenant ID).

```
domain.com/api1 -> api1.azurewebsites.net
domain.com/api2 -> api2.azurewebsites.net
domain.com/api3 -> api3.azurewebsites.net
```

This is slightly simplified, but it shows the point.

All 4 of the App Services/Function are VNet Integrated into their own Subnets, with serverFarms delegations on each, and Service Endpoints to Microsoft.Web. All 4 App Services also have Access Restrictions applied to only allow traffic from the Subnets.

For some reason though, traffic from the Proxies Function App is not getting through to the Web APIs due to Access Restrictions. When I whitelist the External IP addresses of the Function App to the App Services, the traffic is allowed through. This seems wrong to me, as I thought they would be using the private service endpoints which are whitelisted through the subnet?

Does anyone know if this is expected behaviour?

[image: Mini arch diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Premium EP1 Instance at the time of use is a Preview instance, and the VNet Integration feature is also in Preview. The instance had not been whitelisted to allow the use of VNet Integration.

Microsoft were kind enough to whitelist it for us to allow testing.

Answer (score 0):

Now, with the Application gateway V2 SKU, you can do the header rewrite. So, to simplify your configuration, you can remove the Azure Functions from your environment and white-list Application Gateway IP in the Web App.

You can check about the HTTP rewrite in Application gateway [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers).

Comment: It's extremely expensive though!

Comment: And it is only available in UK West, we need one in both UK Regions for failover purposes.